# allow commas in java processing

Tags: java, character, processing

So I have a class that has a boolean attribute `letters` and `numbers` for what kind of characters are allowed to be written with it. I also want to allow commas and spaces, so I tried the following method:

```
  boolean check(char letter){
    if(this.letters){
      if((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') || (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')){
        return true;
      }
    }
    if(this.numbers){
      if(letter >= '0' && letter <= '9'){
        return true;
      }
    }
    if(letter == ' ' || letter == ','){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

for some reason, the if statement `if(letter == ' ' || letter == ',')` does not run even if the key pressed is the comma or spacebar. **Why does this not work?**

Comment: I think key should be letter.

Comment: Java's `Character` class has an `isLetter(char)` function...

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati yes for readability, but it makes no difference here

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thanks for the info. I will use that for the beginning, but that does not help with my problem

Comment: Why you have `char letter` in function input? You don't use it in this function. It works in [this simple code](http://pastebin.com/LJGCNQbZ) so the problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: @Majlik char letter is for readability because in certain instances (but not the way I am using it), using key would not work. You were right my problem was elsewhere. It's fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean check(char ch) {
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) ||
           Character.isSpaceChar(ch)     ||
           ch == ',';
}
```

If you are using `KeyEvent`, make sure you cast your incoming character to an integer to inspect its value

```
System.out.println(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA); // 44
System.out.println((int)',');          // 44

System.out.println(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); // 32
System.out.println((int)' ');          // 32
```

I wrote a very simple Java Swing application that validates each key press. I had to check if shift was being held down, when the user types a digit or presses the comma key.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Foo extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea ara;
    private JScrollPane scr;
    private JLabel lbl;

    public Foo() {
        initComponents();
        addChildren();
        addListeners();

        this.setFont(null);
        this.setTitle("Character Validator");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        ara = new JTextArea(4, 60);
        scr = new JScrollPane(ara);
        lbl = new JLabel("Waiting for input...");
    }

    protected void addChildren() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(scr, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    protected void addListeners() {
        ara.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }            

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (isValidKey(e.getKeyChar(), e.isShiftDown()))
                    setMessage("Valid!", 0x007F00);
                else
                    setMessage("Invalid!", 0x7F0000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setMessage(String message, int color) {
        lbl.setText(message);
        lbl.setForeground(new Color(color));
    }

    protected boolean isValidKey(char keyChar, boolean isShiftDown) {
        boolean validDigit = Character.isDigit(keyChar) && !isShiftDown;
        boolean validLetter = Character.isLetter(keyChar);
        boolean validSpace = keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
        boolean validComma = keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA && !isShiftDown;

        return validDigit || validLetter || validSpace || validComma;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using processing...so this would be unnecessary i believe

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a simplified version of your code, and it works fine for me. Here's my complete sketch which you might want to try:

```java
boolean g_letters = true;
boolean g_numbers = true;

void setup() {}
void draw() {}

void keyPressed()
{
  if(g_letters){
      if((key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') || (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z')){
        println("Pressed: letter");
        return;
      }
    }
    if(g_numbers){
      if(key >= '0' && key <= '9'){
        println("Pressed: number");
        return;
      }
    }
    if(key == ' ' || key == ','){
      println("Pressed: Comma / space");
      return;
    }
}
```

If that sketch works for you, then the problem is somewhere else in your code. I suspect the problem is that you're querying the `key` global variable in your `check()` function (which obviously isn't one of the built-in key handlers). It's not necessarily incorrect to do that, and it might seem to work sometimes. However, if you're not careful, there could be some other code or event modifying `key` before your function sees it.

A better approach would be to take the `key` value in your key-handling function (e.g. `keyPressed()` or whatever you're using), and pass it as an argument through to your `check()` function. That way it's not relying on global state, which is (usually) bad practice in object oriented programming.

With all of that said, I'm making the assumption here that your code is designed to respond *directly* to user input. If you're actually processing characters stored in a string or something, then querying the `key` global variable is completely wrong, as it's designed for user input only. However, the fix would be similar -- you'd just pass the character into your `check()` function instead of the `key` value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your function depends on external parameters... I created a simple example with it and it works:

```
ClassyClass classy;
void setup() {
  classy = new ClassyClass(true, true);
}
void draw() {
  classy.draw();
}
void keyPressed() {
  classy.check(key);
}
class ClassyClass {
  boolean letters = true;
  boolean numbers = true;
  ClassyClass(boolean letters, boolean numbers) {
    this.letters = letters;
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }
  boolean check(char letter) {
    if (this.letters) {
      if ((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') || (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z')) {
        println("its a letter! (" + letter + ")"); 
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (this.numbers) {
      if (letter >= '0' && letter <= '9') {
        println("its a number! (" + letter + ")"); 
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (letter == ' ' || letter == ',') {
      println("its a space or a comma! (" + letter + ")"); 
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  void draw() {
    ellipse(random(10,90),random(10,90),10,10);
  }
}
```